# Java Android redirection of URL doesn't work

Tags: java, android, http, url, redirect

I´m trying to fetch the redirected URL of an URL like this in Java:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL( reUrl ).openConnection());
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            con.connect();
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
            uri = location;
```

But `con.getHeaderField("Location")` gives me null saying there is no such field and `con.getResponseCode()` 200 so there is no redirecting. What am I doing wrong?
example URL: http://hukd.mydealz.de/visit?m=734&q=337105
(hope its OK to post here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you mentioned is not doing a HTTP status code redirect (status code 3xx), but its using HTML's meta refresh tag to redirect. HttpURLConnection can only detect status code redirects (which is 200 in your case).

The best way would be to use a hidden `WebView` and then use `webview.onPageLoadFinished()` to get the final URL of the page. Alternatively, you can parse the html to get meta refresh tag's value to get the redirect url

Comment: thank you for your quick response and solution. think i´m going to parse the link and get the meta url